# What is the fastest way to compute the levels of each node of a directed graph?

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a hierarchical graph represented by two lists of its respective nodes and links, what is the optimal solution to find all the nodes level?

The names of the following nodes are purely fictive, and will not be ordered.
Please note that the source node should be found easily, as it is the only one without parent.

If a special case occur (like multiple levels), only the biggest one should be returned.

Illustration :

[image: Visualisation]

Input:

```
g = Graph()
g.addNodes([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
g.addLink(0, 1)
g.addLink(0, 2)
g.addLink(1, 3)
g.addLink(1, 4)
g.addLink(1, 5)
g.addLink(2, 6)
g.addLink(6, 7)
getLevels(g.nodes, g.links)
```

Output:

```
#Node : Level
0 : 0
1 : 1
2 : 1
3 : 2
4 : 2
5 : 2
6 : 2
7 : 3
```

Comment: What is this? A problem from school? :D
No, really, can you post what your algorithm looks like and where do you believe it could be improved at?

Comment: @RicardPérezdelCampo Not at all, I need it for a personal project.
I'm not very comfortable with recursivity, then my first approach was to append all the nodes between the start and the computed one to a list (representing the road), and get the length of it, which is the level.

The problem is that is slow with big data, plus it don't handle the multiple levels case.

Comment: @RicardPérezdelCampo Well, you're right, the way I wrote my question may lead someone think that it comes from a math problem book. The fact that I had to write some to help students with their homework in the past certainly influenced me when I wrote this question. Should I reformulate it?
I ask because I don't understand why my question has been downvoted

Comment: I was just joking about it. It was actually very well written, that's why it looked strange to me. What I would expect after the question, though, as I already said, is what you had tried so far and where you thought the improvement could be applied. This allows other people to focus more on your real problem. I am not sure about the downvote, but my guess is that it might be just because of this. I took the liberty to upbote it to set it to 0 again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the way you're talking about it, it sounds like you want a tree more so than a graph. Otherwise you're not really coding up a "levels" algorithm but a "distance from node" algorithm. Trees can have levels, you're asking for the farthest distance between two nodes on a graph.

If you're down to code it yourself, you can basically do a [breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) type algorithm, where you take your source node (in this case 0) figure out what's linked to it. If you're returning a map set the keys equal to those nodes and the values to 1. Then find the next links to those, excluding prior nodes, iterate over those and save the values to the map except with a value of 2 now. Loop til you have no more children. If you do this with a tree you get to remove the check to exclude prior nodes.

Comment: A breadth-first-search would indeed be the correct way to approach the given problem. Since he mentions about the possibility of a node having `multiple levels` - it's only possible if there's a cycle in a graph and the input might not always be a tree.

Comment: @ShaneTylerMalachow The fact I may encouter cycles is the reason that pushed me to use a graph rather than a tree (Edit : Thanks nellex for mentioning it)

Comment: @nellex The way I structured the algorithm in my post should handle cycles. Starting from a source and excluding prior levels, you'll eventually overwrite the distance with the greater distance. If you throw a check in there to ignore already determined values, you get the shortest distance from the source.

Comment: There is no problem for me to emplement it by myself, but if I have to, I prefer to use directly the optimal way, so does the BFS is?

Comment: @ChrisProlls I'm not 100% certain but if my algorithm knowledge isn't failing me, this is the most efficient way to get *all* the node distances.

Comment: Okay, I will mark the question as answered if my implementation is fast enough for what I need. This way if someone got a faster solution while I'm coding, I could look for it.

Comment: @ShaneTylerMalachow Excellent, this is fast enough, even for big data. Here is some hints about how to optimize it : [link](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Blake_Lebaron/publication/46554708_A_Fast_Algorithm_for_the_BDS_Statistic/links/0deec51c98afa926ca000000/A-Fast-Algorithm-for-the-BDS-Statistic.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the representation of the tree, you need some mechanism to enumerate the children of a node. Then use a function like

```
TellLevels(Root, Level):
    Say "The node ", Root.Id, " has level ", Level
    for Son= FirstSon(Root) to LastSon(Root)
        TellLevels(Son, Level + 1)
```

and invoke it with

```
TellLevels(Root, 0)
```

This is only valid if the graph has a tree topology.

---

**With cycling avoidance:**

```
TellLevels(Root, Level):
    Root.Visited= true
    Say "The node ", Root.Id, " has level ", Level
    for Son= FirstSon(Root) to LastSon(Root)
        if not Son.Visited
            TellLevels(Son, Level + 1)
```

Comment: As stated in the comments of the previous answer, I should not use a tree due to cyclic behaviour. But thanks for your answer, I may use it in a future project involving family trees

Comment: To avoid cycling, associate a "visited" flag to all nodes. This doesn't change the algorithm much.

Comment: I will compare your two solutions then, is using time.time() the appropriate way? (Saving the time to a variable at start and compare it at the end)